# NetCDF GetCoverage error for WCS v.1.1.0 using GeoServer v.2.10.1

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, wcs, getcoverage

Currently, I have included the NetCDF plugin into GeoServer v.2.10.1 to add data store, which works pretty fine for me to add .nc and .nc4 files including publishing the layer without any error.

Next I would like to see if I can GetCoverage for the NetCDF data store / layer. I was able to get coverage name using GetCapabilities using WCS v.1.1.0 and also using DescribeCoverage operation I was able to get bounding box and CRS details along with supported formats.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CoverageDescriptions schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wcs/1.1.1/wcsDescribeCoverage.xsd">
<CoverageDescription>
    <Title>SRTMTestNC3</Title>
    <Abstract>Generated from NetCDF</Abstract>
    <Keywords>
        <Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
        <Keyword>NetCDF</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Band1</Keyword>
    </Keywords>
    <Identifier>SRTM:SRTMTestNC3</Identifier>
    <Domain>
        <SpatialDomain>
            <BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" dimensions="2">
                <LowerCorner>5.9998611111111115 -1.388888888889E-4</LowerCorner>
                <UpperCorner>7.000138888888889 1.000138888888889</UpperCorner>
            </BoundingBox>
            <BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" dimensions="2">
                <LowerCorner>-1.388888888889E-4 5.9998611111111115</LowerCorner>
                <UpperCorner>1.000138888888889 7.000138888888889</UpperCorner>
            </BoundingBox>
            <GridCRS>
                <GridBaseCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</GridBaseCRS>
                <GridType>urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dGridIn2dCrs</GridType>
                <GridOrigin>6.0 1.0</GridOrigin>
                <GridOffsets>2.777777777777778E-4 0.0 0.0 -2.777777777777778E-4</GridOffsets>
                <GridCS>urn:ogc:def:cs:OGC:0.0:Grid2dSquareCS</GridCS>
            </GridCRS>
        </SpatialDomain>
    </Domain>
    <Range>
        <Field>
            <Identifier>contents</Identifier>
            <Definition>
                <AllowedValues>
                    <Range>
                        <MinimumValue>0.0</MinimumValue>
                        <MaximumValue>0.0</MaximumValue>
                    </Range>
                </AllowedValues>
            </Definition>
            <NullValue>0.0</NullValue>
            <InterpolationMethods>
                <InterpolationMethod>nearest</InterpolationMethod>
                <InterpolationMethod>linear</InterpolationMethod>
                <InterpolationMethod>cubic</InterpolationMethod>
                <Default>nearest neighbor</Default>
            </InterpolationMethods>
            <Axis identifier="Bands">
                <AvailableKeys>
                    <Key>Source</Key>
                </AvailableKeys>
            </Axis>
        </Field>
    </Range>
    <SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</SupportedCRS>
    <SupportedCRS>EPSG:4326</SupportedCRS>
    <SupportedFormat>image/tiff</SupportedFormat>
    <SupportedFormat>text/plain</SupportedFormat>
    <SupportedFormat>application/x-netcdf</SupportedFormat>
    <SupportedFormat>image/png</SupportedFormat>
    <SupportedFormat>image/jpeg</SupportedFormat>
</CoverageDescription>
</CoverageDescriptions>
```

I tried getting coverage using GetCoverage operation of WCS v.1.1.0 but there is some strange error I am getting for that request. (I have tested GetCoverage operation for GeoTIFF's and other data stores / layers, it works fine, problem with only NetCDF).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExceptionReport version="1.1.0" schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ExceptionText>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input argument(s) may not be null.
    The input argument(s) may not be null.</ExceptionText>
</Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

I am using following request.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCoverage&identifier=SRTM:SRTMTestNC3&BOUNDINGBOX=5.9998611111111115,-0.0001388888888889,7.000138888888889,1.000138888888889,urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84&FORMAT=image/tiff&store=true
```

There is not much I can find in logs of GeoServer which input argument is missing, here are the logs.

```
org.vfny.geoserver.wcs.WcsException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input argument(s) may not be null.
    at org.geoserver.wcs.DefaultWebCoverageService111.getCoverage(DefaultWebCoverageService111.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.getCoverage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:850)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input argument(s) may not be null.
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(PlanarImage.java:576)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFResponse.prepareCoverage(NetCDFResponse.java:487)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFResponse.processRequest(NetCDFResponse.java:277)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFResponse.createResponse(NetCDFResponse.java:142)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFSource.read(NetCDFSource.java:65)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.read(NetCDFReader.java:487)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:151)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:232)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:222)
    at org.geoserver.wcs.DefaultWebCoverageService111.getCoverage(DefaultWebCoverageService111.java:358)
    ... 100 more
```

I already have NetCDF output plugin installed in GeoServer, and also able to view the same layer using WMS request (using OpenLayers) for GeoServer.

Are there any extra configuration needed to GetCoverage for NetCDF files / output?